Not able to start minikube using --driver=virtualbox on apple silicon M1
I have installed VirtualBox-7.0.15_BETA4-162549-macOSArm64 which is compatible with mac M1 processor. It is successfully installed. I have also successfully installed Minikube using homebrew. Everything went fine.
However, when I go to the terminal and try to start minikube with:
minikube start --driver=virtualbox

it shows me the error

Exiting due to DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver 'virtualbox' is not supported on darwin/arm64

What is the root cause? Virtualbox is successfully installed and I can open it. so why the driver is not supported and how can I resolve this issue?
